# iPhone UIAutomation: Dynamically Added UI Elements Not Displayed When Executing logElementTree()

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, accessibility, ios-ui-automation

I have the following hierarchy of UI Elements:

```
UITableView
- UITableViewCell
-- UIScrollView
--- UIWebView
--- UIWebView
--- UIWebView
```

Now, when I the page initially loads, this is all that is displayed.  But, if the user scrolls to the right, additional UIWebViews will load as the user encounters them.  For example, if the user were to scroll to the right multiple times as fourth UIWebView would be inserted into the UIScrollView.

Now, when I initially load the screen that contains all of these elements, if I execute logElementTree() on the page, all of the elements that I have listed will be displayed.  For example, I might see the following output:

```
4) UIATableView [name:Empty list value:rows 1 to 1 of 1 rect:{{x:0, y:64}, {width:320, height:416}}]
5) UIATableCell [name:OfferCardTableViewCell value:(null) rect:{{x:0, y:160}, {width:320, height:416}}]
6) UIAWebView [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:0, y:160}, {width:320, height:418}}]
6) UIAWebView [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:320, y:160}, {width:320, height:418}}]
6) UIAWebView [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:640, y:160}, {width:320, height:418}}]
```

But, if I scroll to the right and additional UIWebViews get added to the three existing UIWebViews the new UIWebView elements do not show up when executing `logElementTree()`.  I do notice that the x-coordinate has been updated.  For example, after scrolling to the fourth item in the UIScrollView, the UIAWebViews would be displayed with the following coordinates:

```
6) UIAWebView [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:-960, y:160}, {width:320, height:418}}]
6) UIAWebView [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:-640, y:160}, {width:320, height:418}}]
6) UIAWebView [name:(null) value:(null) rect:{{x:-320, y:160}, {width:320, height:418}}]
```

For reference, the newly created UIWebViews are added to the UIScrollView by invoking `[scrollView addSubView:<new_UIWebView_object>]`.  What do I need to do so that the newly created UIWebViews show up when I execute `logElementTree()`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To work around this problem, you need to use the `UIAccessibilityPostNoficiation` function when an element is added or removed.  The `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` notification will probably work.  Failing that, try `UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification`.